# ggplot 2: how to show breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't get ggplot2 to show breaks in horizontal bars. The code is as follows:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    result = c(replicate(50, 'ok'), replicate(17, 'error'), replicate(35, 'notrun')),
    test = 'test',
    count = 'count'
)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=test, y=count, fill=result)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(ok = '#00BA38', error='#F8766D', notrun='gray')) +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    scale_x_discrete(label="") +
    scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(1, 7, 9)) +
    coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` counts automatically if you leave `stat=identity` out. In this case you can leave your count variable out as well:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    result = c( replicate(50, 'ok'), replicate(17, 'error'), 
                replicate(35, 'notrun') ),
    test = 'test' )

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=test, fill=result)) +
geom_bar() + 
coord_flip() + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c(ok = '#00BA38', error='#F8766D', notrun='gray'))
```

To clarify I cite the documentation on `geom_bar()`:

*"By default, geom_bar uses stat="bin". This makes the height of each bar equal to the number of cases in each group, and it is incompatible with mapping values to the y aesthetic. If you want the heights of the bars to represent values in the data, use stat="identity" and map a value to the y aesthetic."*

So what you were doing was putting variable `count` on the y-axis, which had the same string value "count" for each row, and hence could not be represented on a numerical scale.

[image]